# Find region for which F(x,y) = (x+y)^2 is Lipschitz in y

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

As the title says, I need to find such a region.

Taking any x, and any y1 and y2 I used the expression |F(x,y1) - F(x,y2)| and plugged in the function respectively for y1 and y2.

Now I have to find values for x and y such that the following condition (Lipschitz condition) is satisfied:

| 2x + (y1 + y2) | <= k for some k > 0 (indeed after having simplified out the previous expression w.r.t the Lipschitz condition)

My initial idea was to find x for which y = 0 and then the same thing for y1 and y2. This method though is not enough since for x = 0 the region of y1 and y2 for which the condition is satisfied, will have to depend on y1 and y2 directly. It will be better to attain a region such that it will not depend on the variables (obviously). I hope I am not incorrect here.

I cannot seem to find a way to get this region and I would very much appreciate any insight given.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $|x + y| \leq \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$. Show that the absolute value of the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $y$ is bounded above, and hence the function is Lipschitz on the region with respect to $y$. You can also add any compact region and get that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on the region since your function is continuously differentable.

Answer (score 0):

for any given $x$, $F(x,y)$ grows like $y²$ and becomes arbitrarily steep as y → ∞, and therefore is not globally Lipschitz continuous, it is however locally Lipschitz continuous.

The size of the set in which it is Lipschitz, depends on the Lipschitz constant k. For example, for x=0, taking k = 2, the function is Lipschitz continuous in $-1<y<1$. For any x, taking k = 2,the function is Lipschitz continuous in $-1<x+y<1$. For any x and any k, the function is Lipschitz continuous in $-k/2<x+y<k/2$